# Ajax.BeginFrom Not refresh IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in a MVC4 website using

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action","Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Results", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
{
   HTML....
}
<div id="Results"></div>
```

In the same page my script:

```
function OnSuccess() {
         alert("Ok");
         Do More things...
    }
```

Everything works fine (Chrome, FF ...) not in IE (I'm using IE10). The script works and display the alert, but the content is not being rendered. If I click on the page then IE refresh it and shows the content.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try putting the results div inside the form body.

Comment: Hi Dave, it doesn't work

Comment: I see. please add your action method to your post. let's see what it's trying to do.

Comment: Hi I just change the insertionMode to InsertAfter and seems to be working, I can't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the insertionMode to InsertAfter and it is working now